# Style an unordered list

Tags: css, html-lists

I would like to know how to create a self adjusting list that continues to add values to a particular height and then floats the rest to the right and continues the process.

I have added an image to illustrate. I know the answer is probably simple but I cant seem to get a handle on it.

[image]

Comment: Answer is that you should use `column-count` property...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column-count property specifies the number of columns an element should be divided into.

[Link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_column-rule) to the answer.

```
.classname {
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    column-count: 3;

    -webkit-column-gap: 40px; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-gap: 40px; /* Firefox */
    column-gap: 40px;

    -webkit-column-rule: 4px outset #ff00ff; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -moz-column-rule: 4px outset #ff00ff; /* Firefox */
    column-rule: 4px outset #ff00ff;
}
```